# How to determine the rise time to treat if the signal as a transmission line?

Tags: transmission-line, signal-integrity, high-speed, termination, clock-speed

I know that If the length of the track is between 1/6 or 1/4 of the effective length of a feature like an edge a system can be regarded as lumped.

**BUT** A a lot of times, the rise time cannot be taken from the datasheet, I didn't see any parameter that writes about the rise time.
let's take the example [AD7606C-18](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7606c-18.pdf) - I didn't see any value about the rise time of SCLK,
so I don't know if I need to terminate it (series termination) I know the length of my traces in PCB but don't know the rise time of SCLK.

The only thing I can think of is to take the cycle time of the clock and from that try to figure it out according to some kind of rule of thumb, but it still isn't quite right.

Any help?

Comment: Look into IBIS simulation models. They provide information on the dynamic behavior of inputs and outputs.

Comment: The SCLK in AD7606C-18 is an input.

It does not define what the rise time is. It's the device that drives the MCLK output.

Comment: Yeah, but it's funny that the data sheet doesn't specify a maximum (slowest) rise time for the SCLK input.  I would expect better from Analog Devices.

Comment: Max rate for SCLK is 60 MHz, or a period of 16.7 ns.  Worst case duty cycle is 40%, so 6.7 ns minium high or low time.  So estimate 1 ns for a max rise or fall time???